# Can an attacker sniff the encryption details when connecting to a VPN?

Tags: encryption, vpn, sniffing

I thought I would be protected from sniffing if I use a VPN, even in a setting where my traffic is going through a «man-in-the-middle» either by ARP poisoning or an evil twin attack.

Now I was told, that when connecting to the VPN the initial exchange is done in an unprotected environment, and therefore the encryption details could be sniffed as well.

Meaning that my encryption is futile, because the attacker could decrypt the traffic.

I was assuming that encryption keys were exchanged when installing a VPN app, or that the encryption information is somehow protected.
If that was true, would that mean, that if I set up a VPN app while already using an evil twin network, that in that case, my traffic would be unprotected?

Or are these assumptions wrong anyway?

Comment: "Now I was told" -- who said this?

Comment: If this was true, then all SSL/TLS encryption would be futile, too...

Comment: Please look up the term "secure key exchange": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange

Comment: @schroeder Somebody I know and discussed this matter with. Does it matter? I just want to verify his statement or (I would appreciate this more :)) get some counter-arguments.
Thanks for the link. I will look it up.

Comment: I just gave you counterarguments. If this was an online source, we would like the link so that we could review and determine if you misunderstood the statement. As it stands, the person you talked to has no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: As far as I understand exchanging public and private keys is secure. Some VPNs seem to use symmetric keys after exchanging them securely because of speed. This would still guarantee a safe environment. So yeah, I will keep on asking why this should not be safe :).

Comment: Oh and what about an sslsplit. Let's assume that an attacker has set up an rogue access point or some other mitm attack. Could he theoretically sniff my traffic by forging an ssl certificate and routing me through the now unprotected site or is everything encrypted via the VPN tunnel so that this would become impossible as well?

Comment: Oh I somehow just see your last comment now. Actually it is not a link, but a person who told me that. I am currently trying to get more details from that person, but wanted to kind of verify my understanding to have better arguments ready, because I was not a 100% sure.

Comment: TLS uses symmetric keys, too. The keys are exchanged using PKI. As for SSLsplit, please refer to the duplicate question. Possible, but only if the fundamental protections against this sort of attack fail (a.k.a a poorly designed client). Don't try to know more than someone else. Get them to prove to you that their statements are correct. I suspect this person is using faulty logic to fill in gaps in their basic knowledge.

Comment: Ok thanks. That helps a lot. I will keep asking.